# How can I populate Viewmodel list collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How can I  populate list collection in ViewModel

Controller:

```
  SchoolEntities db = new SchoolEntities();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var student= from s in db.Students
        select s.Name.ToList();

        return View();
    }
```

ModelView:

```
     public List<Student>students { get; set;}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to create your ModelView and pass it to the view?

Comment: @Jon, Yes I want to create a ModelView having a collection of all the students and then pass it to the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `ModelView`, populate it and pass it to the view like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var studentList = db.Students.ToList();

    return View(new ModelView { students = studentList });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to return the view as student, in order to use in your views

```
 public ActionResult Index()
{
    var student= from s in db.Students
    select s.Name.ToList();

    return View(student);
}
```